# Why many "normal" string in my flashlog file

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I suddenly find that there are many "normal" trace in my file flashlog.txt (supposed at your Window's location:{SysDrive}:\Documents and Settings{yourName}\Application Data\Macromedia\Flash Player\Logs).

```
normal
normal
normal
normal
normal
normal
1/10/2011 15:32:13.008 [INFO] org.spicefactory.parsley.core.view.impl.DefaultViewManager Add view root: null/flash.display::Stage
normal
normal
normal
```

But when I run the application with the FlashBuilder, the logging in the consul page is ok, it doesn't include any "normal" String.

I am very confused by this, I thought that the output of the flashlog.txt file should be the same as that of the consul of FlashBuilder.And I don't think I have added such a stupid trace in my code.

The question is how can I find out where these "normal" trace come from and how to remove it.

---

**This problem is resolved by restarting the computer as suggested.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're positive they're not coming from your code or any libraries you are using, it's very possible they're from some site you are visiting while developing. Any and all flash movies compiled with trace statements and run in the debug player will output to the flashlog, and it's not uncommon for swf's like these to make it onto the internet.

Comment: Thanks very much. I think your guess is right. Everything goes well after I restart my PC though I didn't find out which site's swf made it.